# Многократное срабатывание отправленной клавиши через SendKeys

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Стоит цель заполнять формы на сайте данными из Excel-я. Подключил на WinForm EO.Browser и в него планирую отправлять нажатия клавиш. Нажатия клавиш, отправляемые через

```
 SendKeys.Send()
```

оборачиваю в команды, которые выполняются из очереди на каждый тик таймера. Проблема в следующем, при маленьком интервале таймера нажатия начинают меняться в порядке или выполняться по несколько раз.

Comment: Используйте `SendWait`, чтобы гарантированно дожидаться выполнения - тогда порядок не будет меняться. Но, полагаю, могут возникнуть проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: В таком случае возникает проблема с дублированием отправленных команд.